# Elements of an annihilator induced by a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

An annihilator is defined as
$Ann_R(M) = \{r \in R | rm=0 \forall m \in M \}$. However, I read that the minimal polynomial of a matrix $A$ generates $Ann_A(V)$. But, I do not understand; what could be the elements of $Ann_A(V)$? I thought that the ring $R$ in $Ann_R(M)$ must be ring, not a single matrix.

Comment: Without knowing where this cane from and the notation they're using, we could only guess what the author meant. Can you supply any details at all?

Comment: Quoted from my notes:
Let $F$ be a field, $A:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation of $V \cong F$. Viewing $V$ as an $F[x]$=module, there exists unique monic polynomial $m_A(x)$ such that $(m_A(x))$ generates the Annihilator of A.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$.  Let $R=\mathbb{R}[x]$,polynomials in one variable.  Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Notice that $V$ is a module over $R$ by letting $x$ act as $A$.
$$Ann_R(V)=\{p(x)|p(x)m=0 \ \forall m\in V\}.$$
That means $Ann_R(V)$ is all polynomials so that when you evaluate them on $A$ you get the $0$-matrix. This is the principal ideal generated by $(x-1)(x-2)$, which is both the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial of $A$.